# GCP datastore sudden extreme data inconsistency (NDB 1.8.0)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, app-engine-ndb

I have 6 months old Py38 standard gae project in europe-west3 region along with Firestore in DATASTORE mode.

Even with Redis as global cache or without, I have never had any inconsistency issues. Immediate (1 sec took the redirect) fetch after put (insert) yielded fresh results, up until last week. I have made some benching and it takes around 30s for put to result in global query. It actually behaves similar to datastore emulator with consistency parameter set to 0.05

I have read a lot about datastore and its eventual consistency [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore), but as the document says, this is true for "old" version. New firestore in datastore mode should ensure strong consistency as per [this part](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode).

> Eventual consistency, all Datastore queries become strongly consistent.

Am I interpreting this claim wrong?

I have also created a fresh project (same region) with only the essential ndb initialization and still extreme "lag".

I'm running out of ideas what could cause this new behavior. Could be that Warshaw datacenter just started and this is causing the issues?

Abstract code with google-cloud-ndb==1.8.0

```
class X(ndb.Model):
  foo = ndb.StringProperty()

x = X(foo="a")
x.put()

time.sleep(5)    

for y in X.query(): # returns 0 results
  print(y)
```

If I get entity its by key, it's there and fresh. It even instantly shows up in datastore admin.

Answer (score 1):

This was also filed as https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/666 .  It turns out Cloud NDB before 1.9.0 was explicitly requesting eventually consistent queries.